# Is there a way to generate hugo files without index.html?

Tags: javascript, hugo, hugo-shortcode, static-generator

I have my static website in hugo, this is the folder structure:

[image: Hugo static site init structure]

I do not why, when I do **hugo -D** to build hugo, it generates the following scaffolding:

[image: Scaffolding Image generated by Hugo]

I just want pricing, terms and privicy page in the root folder after building hugo, with their respective names, not a folder with the name and inside an index.html file.

NOTE: pricing, terms and privacy page are using `single.html`

Answer (score 2):

Hugo defaults to using pretty links, that is to say ending with a trailing slash and no extenstion. That is what you are seeing output, hugo creates an index file in its own directory.

This means you don't get URLs like example.com/pricing.html, which is generally what people prefer.

If you would prefer a flatter structure, and don't mind your pages showing the .html extension, you should enable uglyUrls.

The [URL management documentation for Hugo](https://gohugo.io/content-management/urls/#pretty-urls) details both options.